# Cannot Find Symbol at method CompareTo(E)

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree, comparable

Please help a confused novice. I am currently practicing on implementing binary search trees with methods such as add, remove, contains and toString. I can implement the class to work with integer values, but I cannot figure out how to use generics on binary search trees. I wanted to be flexible and also use Strings for my Binary Search Tree, or maybe my Card class.

```
public class MyTree<E> {

    private class Node implements Comparable<E> {
        private E data;
        private Node left;
        private Node right;
        public Node(E data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
        public int compareTo(E other) { 
            return this.data.compareTo(other); //ERROR HERE 
                                               //(Cannot Find Symbol at method CompareTo(E))
        }
    }

    private Node root;
    private int size;

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void add(E value) {
        this.root = add(value, root);
    }

    private Node add(E value, Node currentRoot) {
        if (currentRoot == null) {
            Node temp = new Node(value);
            size++;
            return temp;
        } else {
            if (currentRoot.compareTo(value) > 0)
                currentRoot.left = add(value, currentRoot.right);
            else if (currentRoot.compareTo(value) < 0)
                currentRoot.right = add(value, currentRoot.right);
            return currentRoot;
        }
    }
```

I get one error.

```
return this.data.compareTo(other);
                 ^
symbol: method compareTo(E)
location: variable data of type E
where E is a type-variable:
 E extends object declared in class MyTree
```

Why isn't compareTo found when I have a compareTo(E other) in my Node class. I implemented the Comparable interface in my Node class, and I can't figure out why. I've also tried using implements Comparable, but that also doesn't work.

Comment: You probably mean `Node<E>` instead of `Node`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have passed `E` as parameter to `Comparable` but it is not defined. Generally the class which implements `Comparable`, pass itself as parameter to `Comparable`(as generic parameter). `Comparable` should be used to compare instances of the same type. But if you look at your implementation you are not comparing two instances of this class you are only comparing one instance of your class with the filed `value` of another instance in the following line of `add` method:

```
if (currentRoot.compareTo(value) > 0)
```

You can see `currentRoot` is of type `Node` and value is of type `E`. Which is a wrong implementation because if you want to have type safety you should not compare values of different type togehter (or if you want to compare them, they should never be equal to each other because they have different type) so why don't you just compare those two `values` to each other?

On the other hand `E` is generic type and it is not only for `Node` class, `E` is used in the `add` method of your `MyTree` class too. So `E` should be the generic parameter of class `MyTree` and you should let the user of  `MyTree` class decide what the exact type of `E` is when he wants to use `MyTree` class. Another Constraint is that `E` should implement `Comparable` because we want to compare instances of type `E` to each other.

Finally your class will change to this one:

```
public class MyClassTree<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    private class Node {
        private E data;
        private Node left;
        private Node right;

        public Node(E data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    private Node root;
    private int size;

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void add(E value) {
        this.root = add(value, root);
    }

    private Node add(E value, Node currentRoot) {
        if (currentRoot == null) {
            Node temp = new Node(value);
            size++;
            return temp;
        } else {
            if (currentRoot.data.compareTo(value) > 0)
                currentRoot.left = add(value, currentRoot.right);
            else if (currentRoot.data.compareTo(value) < 0)
                currentRoot.right = add(value, currentRoot.right);
            return currentRoot;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Life saver! Thank you very much and my code compiles and it works along with add, remove,toString, contains methods! I do have one inquiry though: ------------- With MyClassTree<E extends Comparable<E>>, does this mean that the generic object I pass to the class should have a compareTo(E), otherwise it won't compile?---------

Comment: @IvanSyrups Yes, and that is exactly what we want. We want  instances of type `E` to be comparable to each other, and  that means they should provide(and implement) `CompareTo` method so that we can use that method in our `add` method implementation.

Comment: or even better, `public class MyClassTree<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`

Comment: @newacct Oh I see, but you lost me there. What is the ?, and where is the super E from? Sorry, I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @newacct Yes that is better I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a compareTo method within the E type - which doesn't have this method. By implementing the interface, *your class* inherites the method, not an unknown type parameter class. Meaning: You have to create the custom comparing mechanics in the Node class.

(Note: you can also check if E implements Comparable, but it is more difficult, and might not be possible during compilation-time.)

(Note 2: If you are confused, just think that Comparable means that instances of the implementing class can be compared to E type objects. This isn't even the implementation you want.)

Comment: "Meaning: You have to create the custom comparing mechanics in the Node class" What do you mean by this? I'm not allowed to compare the data of node classes because of E?

Comment: ^^Pressed enter too early

Comment: By implementing Comparable, your class claims that it can compare itself (or its data field in your implementation) to an other E type. But when are these two equal? When is one greater than the other? Your class should know that. For more information check https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: If you don't want (or can't) implement comparing mechanics in your Node class, your only choice is to accept Comparable<E> instances as data instead of E. This makes sure you can compare them to each other.